# How can I specify a second "site URL" in my facebook application to support localhost development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Facebook login on my site currently working on my development environment.  The "site URL" I have specified in the Facebook application settings is :

```
http://127.0.0.1.
```

I am about to roll this out to production and will change the "site URL" to "http://mysite.com", however this will cause my development setup not to be able to login to Facebook.  I suppose I could create a second facebook application.  I have seen this question asked in slightly different ways but with no definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally put mysite.com in the facebook settings, then change my hosts file so it redirects something like dev.mysite.com to localhost

In FB Dev - mark your app domain as "mysite.com", which will match *.mysite.com

then in your hosts file (google for how to edit this in your environment) add
127.0.0.1   localhost    dev.mysite.com

Then in your browser, go to dev.mysite.com and since fb is setup on the root it should be all good!

Answer (score 0):

You simply add a Test App in Facebook.

Go to developers.facebook.com and click on the "My Apps" tab and select the App that you are working on.
Then, in the left column (below Dashboard, Settings, Status & Review, etc.) you click on "Test Apps". From there, you can create a copy of you App. (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps for more details.)

Now you will have two Apps: MyMainApp, and MyMainApp - Test1.
Each App will correspond to the same code base but you can set up a different 'Site URL' under 'Settings' for each one.
E.g. For MyMainApp, you may have a site URL of 'myMainApp.azurewebsites.net', and for the 'MyMainApp - Test1' you may have a site URL of 'localhost:3000'

**Important**: Each app (for production and test) has its own unique App Id. You need to ensure that you use the correct Id with the Facebook API.
I'm doing the following for my login page:

```
js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=' + facebookAppId + '&version=v2.0';
```

I'm using nodejs/express and I'm setting up the correct facebookAppId via configuration.
You can do something simple like:

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') { 
    // set facebookAppId to the test App Id 
} 
else { 
    // set facebookAppId to the prod App Id 
}
```

Now you can hit your test site using localhost:3000 and you can hit your production site using myMainSite.azurewebsites.net without modifying your hosts file.